# Steps to set the SVN (Subversion) for a folder

Tags: php, codeigniter, svn

I am new to SVN. Can anybody help me set up SVN? I have downloaded SVN to my computer and installed it. I want to come that green tick in my CodeIgniter project. I am not able to make it green tick. Please help.

Comment: If you are new to Subversion you better skip it and start directly with [Git](http://www.git-scm.com).

Comment: @axiac The poster asked for help specifically with Subversion. Telling him to use Git without understanding his situation is not helpful. The company may be 100% using Subversion, in which case he has no option but to use it.

Comment: @alroc You are absolutely right. But if the OP's entire company is using Subversion I think he would get help from his workmates and wouldn't scream for help on SO :-)

Comment: thank you both of you , i managed to use tortoise svn itself to find the commit and update, initially i donot know the purpose of commit  and update . Thank you both, i will keep you in prayers to Jesus Christ

Answer (score 2):

Were you able to check out the code?

The standard way to check out the code would be to create a folder, navigate to that folder, right click and select `svn checkout`.

Comment: Use GITHUB for online SVN

Comment: yes sir, i checked out the code, i created a new folder and checkout, all the files are loaded inside. but i dint get green tick..:(

Comment: GITHUB doesnot have that provisions.But It saved your file with version control

Comment: Since you have checked out the code, your files should be saved with version control, you can just have a look at the logs.

This link: http://www.sitepoint.com/missing-tortoisesvn-file-status-overlay-icons/ may be helpful if you are using tortoise svn.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @helmbert: This post clearly helped the author of the question (which seems a little off-topic here). I can't see anything that justifies its deletion.

Answer (score 1):

For command line and, more important, for concepts, take a look at [Subversion's documentation](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/).

You did not specify what client software you are using. From your references to the "green tick" it might be TortoiseSVN. Check its [documentation](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/index.html)

A short tutorial for Subversion and TortoiseSVN can be found at: https://wiki.alliedmods.net/Subversion_tutorial